# How to check if the bot has the right to enter the voice Discord.js v13

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I recently touched on the topic of checking for connection rights / talking in the bot, but it ignores and gives an error when writing a command

```
if (!message.guild.me.permissions.has('CONNECT'))
    return message.channel.send(`I don't have rights`)
```

Error:

> Cannot destroy VoiceConnection - it has already been destroyed
> There was an Error while starting the Voice Stream```

The module I use is discord-music-player. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first of all, your code only checks if the bot has connection perms in the guild, not if the bot can connect to the specific voice channel. Use [`channel.joinable`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/VoiceChannel?scrollTo=joinable) to check for whether the bot can join the specific voice channel. Assuming you have the voice channel instance saved in the variable `voiceChannel`, here's an example:

```js
if (!message.guild.me.permissions.has('CONNECT') || !voiceChannel.joinable) {
    return message.channel.send(`I don't have rights`)
}
```

That answers your direct question of how to check if the bot can enter the voice channel.

However, the error `Cannot destroy VoiceConnection - it has already been destroyed` may not have anything to do with this question at all. It might be an entirely separate issue; if you are still getting this error after implementing the above solution, you need to ask a different question specifically about that error (and with the relevant code, which you did not include in this question).